# How to trigger same function of two different jQuery version using simple code snippet..?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to register onchange event on this select box ..

```
   <select id="demo">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
    </select>
```

There are two versions of jQuery included on my page that are separated using noConflict

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $m = $.noConflict(true);

      </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have put this code in the script tag..

```
<script>
        $("div#hello").on("change","select#demo",function (){
            console.log("in $ on function");
        });
        $m("select#demo").on("change",function(){
            console.log("in $m on function");
        }); 
</script>
```

I have triggered onchange event on selectbox using

```
$("#demo").val("Orange").trigger("change")
```

then it execute the

```
 $("#demo").on("change",function(){..})
```

but don't execute the second one

```
($m("#demo")..)
```

How can I trigger the onchange event which calls both the event handlers `($ and $m)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this by using jQuery, but you can do it by dispatching a plain javascript event like this:

```
var event = new Event('change', {
    bubbles: true
});

$("#demo").val("Orange")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Working Example**

```js
$("div#hello").on("change","select#demo",function (){
 console.log("in $ on function");
});
$m("select#demo").on("change",function(){
 console.log("in $m on function");
});

$('#trigger_event').on('click', function(e) {
  var event = new Event('change', {
    bubbles: true
  });
 
  $("#demo").val("Orange")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $m = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello">

<select id="demo">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>

</div>
<button id="trigger_event">Trigger Event</button>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the same technique and now triggers the event on document ready without clicks. Tested on Chrome, IE and Mozilla and it's working fine:

```js
$("div#hello").on("change","select#demo",function (){
    console.log("in $ on function");
});
$m("select#demo").on("change",function(){
    console.log("in $m on function");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('On document ready');
    
    var event = new Event('change', {
        bubbles: true
    });
        
    $("#demo").val("Orange")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $m = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hello">

<select id="demo">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>

</div>
```

My working test link: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/multijq-trigger/

As you can see it's even working inside the document ready event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , is there any other way to achieve this without button onclick event like using document.ready or onload.

Comment: @DarshitPatel of course. It will work in anywhere you put the `dispatchEvent` inside. Did you try it and it does not work? **EDIT:** Tell me how you want to use it and maybe I can help you.

Comment: Yes i tried it but it didn't work, when i put `dispatchEvent` in document.ready like 
`$(document').ready( function() {
  var event = new Event('change', {
    bubbles: true
  });
 
  $("#demo").val("Orange")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
});`
but it didn't work

Comment: Well, there is something wrong you are doing there, because it is working for me just dispatching the change event on **document ready**. See my updated answer for the **working code** and my working links.

Comment: I also see you have a typo error there.... `$(document').ready( ... )` there is a single quote after the word document... That would generate a javascript error and stop the execution of the script.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It worked completely in my sample code but it's not working when i used your solution in development environment where there are few third party Javascripts. As, it is not showing any error on console, so it is difficult to figure out where the problem is. According to the privacy policy, I can not put the code here. If you have any other solution then ping me up.

Comment: Well, you could provide some altered sample code of your development environment so I can assist further and help you make it work. My answer is correct and solves the problem addressed in your question for **How to trigger same function of two different jQuery version using simple code snippet**. I think you should mark it as accepted, but it doesn't really matter.